# Insert using SqlDataSource in code behind on it's own thread

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading

I have a `sqldatasource` and I need to have a modal pop up before the insert, and a modal form to close after. I think, I can do this if I execute the insert on it's own thread. How do I do that in this situation? I looked into it and only found examples using SQLConnection.

```
 Protected Sub CreateAdditionalBatch()

     '- Do Something before
     SqlDataSource_ESignCreateFormulation.Insert()
     '- Do something after

 end sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you do, in *pseudo code*, I don't remember exact syntax

```
private Event InsertCompleted 

sub ThisSubDoesInsert()
    ' insert here . . . . 
    Raise Event InsertCompleted
end sub

Sub ThisSubOpensModal()
    using f as new MyForm(ThisSubDoesInsert) ' may need AdressOf(...)
        AddHandler Me.InsertCompleted, AddressOf f.SubThatWillCloseForm 
        f.ShowModal()
        RemoveHandler Me.InsertCompleted, AddressOf f.SubThatWillCloseForm
    End using
End sub
```

And in form

```
class MyForm
    private _callback AS Action ' - set this in constructor

    sub Form_Load
        Me.Show()
        _callback() ' This will call insert
    end sub

    sub SubThatWillCloseForm()
        Me.Close()
    end sub

End Class
```

In this code, you call a method that pops up the modal form while passing a callback to do insert once modal is open. When insert completes, the event is fired. This event is wired to a form method that will close the form. This is pseudo code, you need to make it real. No need for multi-threading here.

Comment: Thank you for the answer T.S, I will attempt to implement it when I get home and update as answer if it works.